# Change administrator editor

Tags: joomla, text-editor, administration, markdown

Is it possible to change the default administration editor in Joomla 1.5?

I've tried installing Textile and Markdown editors, but those are only installed for on page editing and not in administration management...

### Questions

1. is it possible to change default administration editor
2. how can I change it to some markdown (or markdown like) editor

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes; you can set a default editor in Joomla general configuration settings, choosen among every editor you installed; and you can also override this setting on a "per-user" basis, in the profile of the user.
2. When installed, your new editor (Textile or not) will be present in the editor select list, both in general configuration and in user profile configuration.